# Agendar script php no windows

Tags: php, windows, agendamento

Olá, tenho um script em php que preciso rodar automaticamente de 15 em 15 minutos no windows (meu sistema está hospedado localmente).

Bom, vi que tem que ser pelo agendador de tarefas do windows então configurei da seguinte forma:
Adicionei uma tarefe básica e selecionei para iniciar o Chrome e nos argumentos coloquei o caminho do script (localhost/script.php).

Está funcionando direitinho, o problema é que toda vez que a tarefa é executada, ele abre uma novo Chrome, então fica dezenas de Chromes abertos.

gostaria de saber se existe algum outro modo de fazer esse agendamento ou algum comando ou opção pra executar a tarefa na janela ja aberta ou simplesmente recarregar a página, pois como o script ficará rodando 24h por dia, uma hora alguém terá que fechar essas janelas.

Comment: Não sei como funciona esse agendador de tarefas, mas pela lógica, o que eu pensei é: Abra pela primeira vez e agende uma tarefa para apertar F5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, consegui resolver, fiz o bat com o comando para executar o script mas estava dando erro.
primeiro faltava adicionar a variável PHP nas variáveis do ambiente entao adicionei o caminho do php.exe no Path

então, tive problemas com os arquivos de "include" do meu script, tive que mudar o código para include(**DIR** . '/config.php');

Agora está funcionando direito.

Agradeço a ajuda de vocês!

Comment: blz... marca como resolvido

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa executar pelo browser.

Execute o PHP por linha de comando.

No agendador de tarefas apaenas especifique o mesmo comando que usaria pelo cmd (prompt)

```
c:\local\do\compilador\php.exe -f c:\local\do\script.php
```

Esteja ciente que algumas funcionalidades comportam-se de forma diferente sob CLI (command line interface), mas, normalmente não terá problemas.

*Prefira especificar o caminho completo do compilador e do script a executar. Evite camihos relativos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um arquivo **.bat** que execute sua página php, e seu **bat** você coloca no agendador de tarefas.

***o conteúdo do bat ficará da seguinte forma***

```
php -f arquivo.php
```

Comment: Olá, eu tentei tanto em .bat quanto colocando os comando direto no agendador, ele executa mas não faz nada.. sabe se tem algum log que eu possa ver o que esta acontecendo?

Comment: não sei se é pq to usando wamp